# Bootstrap image on navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have to say that i am a beginner in web design, I am trying to make a website with bootstrap and Dreamweaver CC and I have navbar and I am wondering how can a place an image at the center of the navbar but to be on the same row. Can you guys please help me?

```html
<div class="navbar-header">
      <center><img src="71f7c350c2d7d3a6eb8394f66185a3e7.jpg" alt="" width="40" height="54"/></center>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#topFixedNavbar1"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Liceul Teoretic "Victor Babeș"</a></div>
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="topFixedNavbar1">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div>
<!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Show us what you have and we can help

Comment: So, I don't understand how to place code on this site but I can tell you what I've done, so, I've included the img src in the navbar header and I used a center tag to do that but it wasn't even on the center and it was on a separated row

Comment: @FlaviusDolha just edit your question and paste your code. Check out the [Site Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and welcome to the site!

Comment: Click edit your question and if you can't find where you paste your code just press Ctrl + M. A code snippet bar will appear. Where you can shear you code.

Comment: Done, thanks to both you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use absolute positioning to get the img in the center.

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px !important; //this pixel amount is equal to half your image size
    display: block;
}
```